# Passiv das ein substantiviertes Verb bestimmt

Tags: passive

So I'm contemplating the sentence

> Große Preissteigerungen sind nicht zu befürchten.

Obwohl das Passiv das Agens verschleiert, verstehe ich diesen Satz eindeutig wie den folgenden:

> Große Preissteigerungen sind nicht (von den Käufern) zu befürchten.

Hier ist "die Käufer" das Agens des Verbs *befürchten*.
Ich frage mich, ob man auch andere Präpositionalphrase einsetzen könnte:

> Große Preissteigerungen sind nicht *von den Herstellern* zu befürchten.
> Große Steigerungen sind nicht *von den Preisen* zu befürchten.

Hier, sofern diese Sätze auch korrekt sind, würde sich der *von*-Phrase auf das Verb *steigern* (in *Steigerung*) beziehen, was irgendwie auch eine Art Passivkonstruktion ist. Ist mein Verständnis korrekt? Oder müssen diese Sätze anders gebaut werden, um die Steigerung zu bestimmen?

Comment: "von" ist hier eine mehrdeutige Präposition - Sie kann sowohl meinen, dass die Steigerung *an* den Preisen/Herstellern,... liegt, als auch *durch* sie befürchtet wird.

Answer (score 2):

> Große Preissteigerungen sind nicht zu befürchten

Das ist ein sehr "komprimierter" Satz - in ihm passieren mehrere Dinge gleichzeitig:

- Die Preise steigen (oder nicht)
- jemand fürchtet sich vor dieser Entwicklung (oder nicht)

Das unpersönliche Passiv in diesem Satz bezieht sich auf das "fürchten" - nicht auf die Preise. Was du aber möchtest, ist, anzugeben, wer das "steigern" verursacht, also etwas mit den "Preisen" macht. Die "Steigerungen" sind in deinem Satz aber substantiviert, also weder Aktiv noch Passiv. (Deine Frage hat also mit Passiv nur wenig zu tun).

Dazu kurz ein Exkurs:
Bei *Löwenangriffen* ist relativ wahrscheinlich, dass der Löwe angreift und nicht angegriffen wird (obwohl das nicht explizit gesagt wird und auch nicht unbedingt so sein muss).

Bei *Preissteigerungen* ist das nicht so deutlich: Entweder steigern *sich* die Preise (dann sind die Preise schuld und kein eigentlicher Verursacher ist genannt) oder die Preise werden (z.B. vom Hersteller) gesteigert, dann ist offensichtlich der Hersteller der Aktor.

Nun zu deinen Vorschlägen zur Änderung, damit du angeben kannst, wer an den Preissteigerungen "schuld" ist:

> Große Preissteigerungen sind nicht von den Herstellern zu befürchten.

Hier hast du als Präposition "von" gewählt, das ist leider nicht sehr sinnvoll - "von" ist hier mehrdeutig, weil es sich sowohl auf das eigentliche Verb des Satzes (das befürchten) als auch möglicherweise auf den Verursacher der Steigerung beziehen könnte:

> etwas wird von jemand befürchtet

hier gibt "von" an, wer sich fürchtet

> etwas von etwas/jemandem wird befürchtet

hier gibt "von" an, wer etwas tut, vor dem sich jemand fürchtet.

> Große Preissteigerungen sind nicht von den Herstellern zu befürchten.

Kann also sowohl bedeuten, dass der Hersteller die Preise steigert, als auch dass der Hersteller befürchtet, dass die Preise steigen. (Die Position des "von den Herstellern" beim Verb läßt allerdings darauf schließen, dass die Hersteller sich fürchten)

Dem kann man durch eine andere Präposition und eine andere Satzstellung (Aktor "näher" bei der Substantivierten Aktion) abhelfen:

> Preissteigerungen *durch* den Hersteller sind nicht zu befürchten.

> Steigerungen *bei* den Preisen sind nicht zu befürchten

Comment: Wenn man das "von" behalten will: "...von Seiten der Hersteller sind nicht ..."

Comment: Ob man das als 'Passiv' bezeichnen würde? Nach langem Suchen fand ich in der Duden-Grammatik den Begriff 'Passiv-Ersatzkonstruktion', hier eine mit modalem Charakter und '_sein_' als Modalitätsverb: _... müssen nicht befürchtet werden / brauchen nicht befürchtet (zu) werden / muss niemand befürchten._ Man könnte fast inhaltsgleich sagen _... sind / stehen nicht zu erwarten_, oder _Es drohen keine Preissteigerungen_, natürlich auch _Man kann davon ausgehen, dass es keine Pr. geben wird._ Zu all diesen Variationen passen die hier vorgestellten Ergänzungen.